# J2ME Writing in CSV file through file Connection API

Tags: file, java-me, nokia

I am creating an application in which i need to add a new column in the csv file and then entries for that particular column.

And I have tried OutputStream and PrintStream but the problem is that the data is being written in starting of the file but i want the data at random position according to my need.
And RandomAccessFile is not identified by the application.

For e.g.

My CSV is:

Name,any_date

A,

B,

c,

And after writing it will look like

Name,any_date

A,p

B,a

C,p

I am using file Connection API to read and write.Can anyone suggest me how to do that??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

i think you want to append data in the file.

you can try this

```
 os = fconn.openOutputStream(fconn.fileSize());  
        os.write(data.getBytes());
```

This is a simple example to append data at last.

Comment: but i dont want to append,i want to write at random places in file by giving the offset or any other method.But i am not getting how to do that?

Comment: So i think what you can do is read file.csv , write complete data in temp.csv , delete file.csv and rename temp.csv to file.csv

Comment: For that you can use delete() and rename(String newName) methods of FileConnection.

Comment: can you provide me some link on which i can see this type of file writing?